# Adding Qmake Command option in c/c++ tools options in Netbeans

Tags: c++, compilation, qmake

I want to know from where can I add Qmake command option in the tool option in the Netbeans, do I need toolkit before I add the Qmake command or is it like it is there in the msys/bin directory.

I am using Netbeans 7.1.1 and gcc version is 4.6.1.

Comment: Well, where did you install Qt? Also, are you using gcc or MinGW gcc? You talk about MSYS but your question says gcc and you removed MinGW from it.

Comment: Well i am running MinGW gcc (Mingw Installer version 20111118), i have still not made use of QT but i doubt if need to make use of it

Comment: Tell me the procedure...

Comment: My question is, do you actually need to use QMake and no other make-program, or does GNU Make suffice?

Comment: Well i am using make command however in one of my projects i need Qmake as it does not even compile without the use of qmake command

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Qt. You can find it [here](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate  on the settings that i need to take care of while installing QT